# What should we do when a user deletes their post for lack of feedback?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/170738/force-inactivity-lock-on-application-that-circumvents-it) and the first user to answer it deleted their answer with comment:

> I have deleted my answer, [since] there was no feedback from you as requested.

I don't remember the entire answer, but it seemed to have useful points for me to research.

This looks like rage deletion to me i.e. revenge for not complying with whatever "requested feedback" he demanded in arbitrary time period he considers "acceptable". And as far as I remember rage/revenge is frowned upon because it gives quite bad impression of Stack Exchange sites to general user. What can be done about such behavior?

Answer (score 4):

It seems that way to me as well, and I don't understand why it happened in this case.

I have undeleted the answer.  In the future, you can simply flag your question an explain there (though coming to Meta was totally fine here, and thank you for doing so).

Answers are ultimately community property here and should not be deleted if they are useful answers to the question.  SE can disassociate answers from user profiles in exceptional cases if need be, but it's up to the author to contact them about it.

Comment: Mathew - I do remeber the chat we had about an year ago. Please see my reply

Answer (score 1):

I am the one who deleted answer

Your assumption is valid given my explanation in comments - which was incomplete and should have clarified more

I tested the macro with one "screen holding" app and the results were surprising - sometimes it would work, other times it wouldn't. That's why I requested for a feedback while posting the answer and in the absence of which, assumed that it didn't work for you and hence was not a working solution and deleted

I should have explained the circumstances clearly, to avoid this misunderstanding and confusion, as I did on the case of another [self deleted answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/170761/power-management-configuring-battery-cutoff-voltage#comment218523_170761)

Sorry for this and will take care to clarify adequately in case such a situation arises

BTW - I am still interested in the feedback to figure out erratic behaviour

Answer (score 1):

I do share the same sentiments at times, sometimes it's worth **sharing the feedback** to the poster of the answer so that the author may be assured their post was helpful.

Honestly I think  getting feedback from time to time is very important.  Some users indeed put so much effort and time their when acquiring and researching information when posting answer to assist the asker in the best way possible, so its really encouraging to get feedback from the asker on the whether the given answer was helpful or not (its not necessarily about upvoting or anything) but just a **comment** is worth it.

Of course time won't permit every user to do that, in that case its okay, otherwise a small feedback will do much good to encourage users to post quality answers and reduce trash and this will help the community at large.

Comment: Well I don't agree with taking down an answer unless its poster identified and mentions in the comment (before deleting it) *a reasonable issue* with the answer (it being incorrect; inherently bad based on an assumption, etc.). That aside, I totally agree with your answer. Sometimes, and when I used to answer a lot, I always expected that the poster at least provide feedback, if not accept or upvote my answer.