# Why so few people to vote?

Tags: discussion

I've been discovering Android Enthusiasts SE and although I kind of like the topic, my impression is that this SE is not doing great. I've been active on a few other SE sites for some time and one can really tell the difference. Apparently there's just not enough regular active members for the flow of questions ([58% answered](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology-traffic)). Crucially there are very few votes being cast, and this is quite bad given that the SE model relies on votes.

**More downvotes :**
I understand that for question asking, if quality is low or it looks like there was not sufficient effort or time put into asking a question it can be downvoted.

I feel like by penalizing downvotes we are discouraging people from holding answers to higher standards.

Interested to hear you guys thoughts on this

I understand that for question asking, if quality is low or it looks like there was not sufficient effort or time put into asking a question it can be downvoted.

**So what I'd like to know is:**

**Why so few people vote?** Is it because there are not enough "avid members", too much turn-over, too many questions, questions being too specialized (or not enough)... ?

**What can be done about it?** (if anything) More precisely, as a modest active member, what should I prioritize? 
For instance, I've seen other sites which encourage:

- [**Vote early and vote often:**](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/19/vote-early-vote-often/) should I vote on questions/answers even if I don't feel very confident about the topic?
- voting to close out-of-scope/unclear questions early (and harshly) in order to force the user to clarify before (possibly) re-opening. But of course, that's not very welcoming.
- be more strict about duplicates: many beginners questions are variants of existing questions, should I vote to close as duplicate even if it's not exactly the same question?
- any other suggestion...?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Android.SE :) This is a known long-term issue and has been a big topic in previous elections (further reading: [Role of Moderators and others in increasing the strength and involvement of the backbone of the community](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2465)). While all the answers are insightful, I'd particularly put the highlight on [iBug's answer](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2468/44325) since it very relates to me personally: the Android fragmentation itself. Most often, I don't have confidence in (up/down/duplicate)-voting on troubleshooting questions.

Comment: (also, the linked questions on that question, including [How can we spend some effort on improving our overall activity?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2380) from 2017 and [You need the bourgeois blues](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/578) from 2011)

Comment: As brought out, this is an old issue with no real solutions. Only suggestion is *be the change, you want to see!*, in other words, vote as much  as you can except of course when the quality is poor or wrong or not meeting site standards (link only answers etc)

Comment: Do to others what you want from them to do to you. By your voting, try to inject the maximal information into the system. The maximum is if you vote about third of the posts up, third of them down, and third abstain. You do not want to lose the -1 on answer downs, so downvote answers only if they really deserve. Read also [this](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2627/50837).